# How to insert Revolution Slider manually using Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, revolution-slider

I am inserting the revolution slider using a shortcode on the WordPress page in the page editor:

```
[rev_slider test]
```

However, when the page is published, the revolution slider is not showing and Chrome console shows javascript error. When I view source, Wordpress wraps

tags around the revolution slider javascript code.

Is there a way to manually add a revolution slider to a WordPress page using javascript such as:

```
revSlider.load('slideContainer', 'test');
```

So far I have not found any way to inject or insert the javascript code for a revolution slider into a WordPress page.

Comment: Did you add the shortcode in the Text mode of the editor?

Comment: @Benoti yes, both ways. I also tried inserting the php shortcode for Rev Slider using the Insert PHP plugin which caused the same error in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that it's wrapping the entire thing in `<p>` tags?

To avoid this, add the following to your functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop',100 );
```

Used with the following to make sure it's not wrapping all your content:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

If that still doesn't help, there's a PHP solution here:
[How to Add a Slider without A Shortcode or Widget](https://www.themepunch.com/faq/how-to-add-a-slider-without-using-a-shortcode/)

Comment: I put that exact line in functions.php and it did not work. Thank you though.

Comment: Perhaps used in conjunction with:
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );